# Compiling external Matlab function code

Tags: c, matlab, mex

I'm trying to compile an external Matlab function C code to use the function with my Matlab (2013a). When I type "make" I get an error "mex: command not found". How can I successfully compile the function? I'm using OS X 10.9.

To be more specific, I'm trying to install the function SVMStruct (from http://www.robots.ox.ac.uk/~vedaldi/code/svm-struct-matlab.html#ssvm.download) but lack of mex command on my mac prevents from doing so. Here is the complete error message

> mex -largeArrayDims - CFLAGS='$CFLAGS  -Wall' LDFLAGS='$LDFLAGS ' -outdir "build//" -c            > "svm_struct_api.c"
>   /bin/sh: mex: command not found
>   make: *** [build//svm_struct_api.o] Error 127

Comment: There is a section in the documentation dedicated to MEX-files: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/write-cc-mex-files.html, http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/what-you-need-to-build-mex-files.html

Comment: From README_MATLAB.txt:

`If MEX is not on the command line, the path can be specified as

> make MEX=<MATLABROOT>/bin/mex

where <MATLABROOT> is MATLAB root directory.`

Comment: That should work but then I get the following error. /Applications/MATLAB_R2013a.app/bin/mex -largeArrayDims - CFLAGS='$CFLAGS  -Wall' LDFLAGS='$LDFLAGS ' -outdir "build//" -c "svm_struct_api.c"

    mex:  - not a valid option.

    Usage:
      MEX [option1 ... optionN] sourcefile1 [... sourcefileN]
          [objectfile1 ... objectfileN] [libraryfile1 ... libraryfileN]

    Use the -help option for more information, or consult the MATLAB External Interfaces Guide.

make: *** [build//svm_struct_api.o] Error 1

Comment: That's weird, it can't detect your architecture.  What is the output of `uname` on your system? Also `uname -sm`. Whatever the case, you can set `ARCH` just like you did for `MEX` when calling make.  Depending on 32-bit vs. 64-bit it will be either `ARCH=maci` or `ARCH=maci64`, respectively.

Comment: The outputs are Darwin and Darwin x86_64, respectively. Then I run make MEX=/Applications/MATLAB_R2013a.app/bin/mex ARCH=maci64

Comment: The error this time is /Applications/MATLAB_R2013a.app/bin/mex -largeArrayDims -maci64 CFLAGS='$CFLAGS -m64 -isysroot /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk -mmacosx-version-min=10.4 -Wall' LDFLAGS='$LDFLAGS -mmacosx-version-min=10.4' -outdir "build/maci64/" -c "svm_struct_api.c"
xcrun: error: SDK "macosx10.7" cannot be located
clang: warning: no such sysroot directory: '/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk'
svm_struct_api.c:20:10: fatal error: 'stdio.h' file not found
#include <stdio.h> ^ 1 error generated. mex: compile of ' "svm_struct_api.c"' failed. make: *** [build/maci64/svm_struct_api.o] Error 1